# How to write regular expression in UE to implement this requirement?

Tags: regex, ultraedit

Now I have a large C++ project which is made up of about 1400k lines of code. Now I have a requirement: Add one line of code to each class which is derived from CDialog, CWnd or CListCtrl. It's impossible for me to do this manually. I think maybe UltraEdit regular expression can give me a hand, but I can't write related regular expression by myself.

Anybody can help me?

Here is the line of code to add:

```
virtual ULONG GetGestureStatus(CPoint ptTouch) { return 0;}
```

and here is my code structure(just for a illustration):

```
class CRibbonAddPlaceDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CRibbonAddPlaceDialog)

public:
    CRibbonAddPlaceDialog();
    virtual ~CRibbonAddPlaceDialog();
    enum { IDD = IDD_RIBBON_ADDPLACE };

protected:
    virtual ULONG GetGestureStatus(CPoint ptTouch) { return 0;}//the line to add
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnDestroy();
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    virtual BOOL OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo);
public:
    BOOL AddButton(CFX_WideString csTitle, AddPlaceButtonProc proc, void* pClientData, CFX_DIBitmap* pButtonImage);
public:

    CReader_RibbonFilePageManager* m_pRibbonFilePageMgr;
    CReader_RibbonStyle_Static*       m_pAddPlace;
    CReader_RibbonStyle_Static*       m_pAddPlaceTip;
    CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, buttondata*> m_arButtonData;
    CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, CBCGPButton*>m_arButton;

};
```

Comment: What OS are you on, Windows?

Comment: yes, I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Then begin to learn regex. It's not hard at all. You may [begin here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to place that line right after the opening `{`, try searching for (with Perl regexes turned on):

```
^(class\b.*\bC(?:Dialog|Wnd|ListCtrl).*\r?\n\{\r?\n)
```

and replace with

```
\1virtual ULONG GetGestureStatus(CPoint ptTouch) { return 0;}\r\n
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i got the warnning message: You have entered an invalid expression.

Comment: You did check the "Perl regex" option?

Comment: yes, i did check the "Perl regex" option, and my UE version is: UltraEdit Professional Text/HEX Editor 
Version 18.10.0.1016.                                               Am i missing something?

Comment: I just tried it in my version (19.00, though), and it works fine there...sure you didn't make a copy/paste error?

Comment: aha, it works fine now, i will accept your answer. you are so professional in regular expression! A superman!

Comment: I have another question, I can't find and replace those class which are padded with several tabs or backspaces. Can you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

`perl -ibak -pe "s/protected:\n/protected:\n    virtual ULONG GetGestureStatus(CPoint ptTouch) { return 0;}/" file_name`

Comment: keep in mind, that it'll add the line after each time `protected:` appears in the file

Comment: a very good answer, in fact, i also want to accept your answer if i can accept two at the same time. I have upvoted your answer and comment.

Comment: thanks. you can only accept one answer - rules of the game :)